# What is returned in the function

Tags: python, opencv, python-multithreading

```py
def frame(self,src=0):
   if self.isOpened():
      (ret, frame) = self.read()
   if not ret:
      print('Failed to Capture Video.........')
   return frame
```

I am using this function to get this

`frame1 = Thread(target = frame(cam1))`

When using Frame1 for `cv2.imshow("Capture", frame1)`, it is returning a error.

I was expecting to see the video output

Comment: Why do you acquire the frame on a separate thread ?

Comment: The thread parameter is the function name without the call  `Thread(target=frame, args=(cam1,))`. And the return value is the thread 
 that you need to `start()` .

Comment: why do you try to return "a frame" regardless of failure/errors?

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. this is not a MRE. it is incomplete, not runnable as is.

Comment: I need the output for four separate rtsp cameras, but keeping videocapture and videoshow in same loop is causing extreme lags for the camera output.